# Standalone laravel script

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a laravel project which is in a process to go live. I want to write a php script which if run from terminal should hash all the passwords in Users table. I am using eloquent. I have the script ready with using usual route and controller but I want a standalone script which if I drop in say my web folder and if I try to run that script from terminal should hash all the passwords. Is there any way to do that? is there a way I will be able to extend eloquent and anything which is required to extend in order to use `Hash::make('password');` this method.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the file, require composer autoloader, use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash, use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, then encrypt and save in DB.

Comment: `require composer autoloader` throws error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'autoloader'`

Comment: no no! I didn't mean that. I mean, require the composer generated autoload file, it should be here: vendor/autoload.php.

Comment: Appreciate your help. But I get one more error `Class 'Eloquent' not found in web/app/Models/BaseModel.php`. I tried adding a class to my standalone script which `extends` `Eloquent` by adding `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;` but even that didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Laravel command (see Reference for [Ver.4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands) or [Current](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan)). Then, you can easily call the command from a "stand-alone" script within www folder with `php artisan YOUR_COMMAND [YOUR_OPTIONS]`.